# Find the derivative of $f(x) = x^{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

Thought I understood this one, but the solution I arrived at is not among the options:

Used $\ln$ and $d$ operators:

$\ln (y) = \ln(x^{\ln x})$ becomes $\ln y = \ln x \cdot\ln x$

Then using $d$ operator:

$$d(\ln y) = d(\ln x \cdot \ln x)$$

Product rule:

$$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{\ln x\, dx}{x} + \frac{\ln x\, dx}{x}$$

and simplify:

$$\frac{dy}{y} = \biggl(\frac{\ln x}{x} + \frac{\ln x}{x}\biggr)dx\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = y\biggl(\frac{\ln x}{x} + \frac{\ln x}{x}\biggr) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

Replace $y$ with value from original function:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2\frac{\ln x}{x}x^{\ln x}$$

But it appears that this is not the correct solution. My sense is that the $x$ in the final denominator should have canceled somewhere, but I've gone through the calculations a few times and arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong (other than the left-hand side should be $\frac{dy}{dx}$ rather than $\frac{dy}{dy}$)?  You could combine the $x$ in the denominator with the $x^{\ln x}$ factor if you wished.

Comment: What is the correct solution? Maybe it is just the same but written differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=x^{\ln (x)}$

$\ln (y)=[\ln(x)]^2$

$\frac{y'}{y}=2[\ln (x)]\frac{1}{x}$

$y'=2y[\ln (x)]\frac{1}{x}=2x^{\ln (x)-1}. \ln(x)$

So your answer seems correct.

Comment: I missed simplifying the $\frac{x^{\ln x}}{x}$ portion of the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$x^{\ln{x}}=e^{\ln{x \ln{x}}}=e^{\ln^2{x}}$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general idea for derivate function like:

$$f(x)=g(x)^{h(x)}$$

The idea is write

$$f(x)=e^{\ln[g(x)]^{h(x)}}=e^{h(x)\ln[g(x)]}$$

Then,

$$f'(x)=e^{h(x)\ln[g(x)]}\left[h'(x)\ln[g(x)]+h(x)\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right] $$

$$f'(x)=g(x)^{h(x)}\left[h'(x)\ln[g(x)]+h(x)\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right] $$

Answer (score 0):

Define the functions $a, b, c$ as follows:

$a(x) = e^{x}$

$b(x) = x^{2}$

$c(x) = \ln x$

Now to verify that $a \circ b \circ c = f$, we have

$a(b(c(x))) = a(b(\ln x)) = a((\ln x)^{2}) = e^{(\ln x)^{2}} = (e^{\ln x})^{\ln x} = x^{\ln x}$

Now use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.

We have that $x = e^{\ln x} \implies y = x^{\ln x} = (e^{\ln x})^{\ln x}  \quad \boxed{\therefore y= e^{\ln^2 x}.}$ We can break $y$ into simpler functions, namely $e^x, x^2$ and $\ln x$ because $y = e^x \circ \ln^2x = e^x \circ(x^2\circ \ln x) = \boxed{e^x\circ x^2\circ \ln  x.}$ So all we need is the chain rule!

Using the previous representations of $y$,
$$\begin{align} 
y^\prime &= \left( (e^x)\circ(\ln^2x)\right)^\prime\\
&= e^{\ln^2 x}\cdot(\ln^2x)'\\
&=y\cdot((x^2)\circ\ln x)^\prime \\
&=y\cdot(2\ln x \cdot\ln^\prime x) \\
&= y\cdot (2\ln x\cdot \frac1x)\\
&= \boxed{2 \frac{\ln x}{x}x^{\ln x}.}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of $2\frac{\ln x}{x}x^{\ln x}$ is essentially correct, though you have written the derivative as $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}y}$, where it should be $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Apart from mistakenly multiplying through by ${\mathrm{d}y}$ instead of ${\mathrm{d}x}$, and some questionable use of notation (e.g. taking the logarithm of an equation, instead of an expression), I don't see anything wrong with your calculation.

To justify to yourself that $2\frac{\ln x}{x}x^{\ln x}$ is indeed the correct derivative, you could try recovering the original function through integration by substitution.

$$\begin{align}
\int 2\frac{\ln x}{x}x^{\ln x}\ \mathrm{d}x&\underset{x\ \mapsto\  e^{t}}{=}2\int t 
e^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t
\\
&\underset{t\ \mapsto\  \sqrt{u}}{=}\int 
e^{u}\ \mathrm{d}u
\\
&=e^{\ln^2 x}+C\quad \square
\end{align}$$